# Continue request flow after new access token is issued using refresh token

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I am not able to figure out how do I continue the request flow after refreshing the expired `JWT` token in my `Flask` application.

I am storing `access token` and `refresh token` in their respective cookies.

This is how my flow looks like right now:

Below is my decorator function that checks validity of the `JWT` token

```py
def check_valid_jwt(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper():
        print(request.cookies)
        if 'access_token_cookie' in request.cookies:
            print('Verify Signature')
            # some code that verifies the JWT signature
            print('Signature verification successful')

            # some code that extracts claims from the token

            if time.time() > claims['exp']:
                print('Token is expired')
                # some code that get the new access token using refresh token
                # What am I supposed to do here after I get the refresh token and continue the request while adding the new token to access_token cookie?
            return f()

    return wrapper
```

Here is how my protected endpoint looks like:

```
@check_valid_jwt
def secretpage():
    return render_template("/home/secret_page.html")
```

After I get the refresh token, I want to continue the flow of the request and add new `access token` in the cookie but if I add that in `check_valid_jwt` decorator function, `secretpage` handler will have no idea that a new `access token` has been issued.

How do I do it in such a way that if a new `access token` has been issued, it gets added to the response. Am I complete off here and this is not how `Authentication` flow works?

Comment: To me the request should end if the token is expired, it's your client's job to refresh the token and try again. But I'm not sure this works for your usecase.

Comment: I want to do that in the worst case scenario when my `refresh token` is also expired, send `401` back. If my `refresh token` is valid, I want to make it simple for the end user.

Comment: If you are sending an access and refresh cookie in every request, there really isn’t a point to having a separate refresh token. Having a longer lived access token would be functionally the same thing, without the refresh flow complexities you are dealing with here.

Comment: @vimalloc The reason I am sending refresh token every request is because I have 30 minutes session requirement. Since there is no session, I have to renew access token for the next 30 minutes if it is not expired. For that I need refresh token.

Comment: It sounds like you want your user to be logged out after 30 minutes of inactivity, is that right? Instead of refreshing the token after it expires, maybe you should pre-actively refresh the token instead. You could create and set a new token if the old token is within 15 minutes of expiring for example.

Comment: I issue access token for 45 minutes as I am expecting my users to finish doing what they are doing in 15 minutes. This way I avoid new token every request. I wanted to keep simple in my comments earlier as I am looking for the solution to send new tokens back to user in non-intrusive way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a middleware for JWT authentication instead of a decorator

```
from flask import Flask


class JWTAuthMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app  

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        access_token = environ.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)

        # validate access token here and get new one if required by using refresh token

        # you can also update the invalid token in the header here if you want

        environ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'new access token'

        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

Now wrap the actual wsgi app with this one

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.wsgi_app = JWTAuthMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)
```

Comment: so is this just a best practice answer or does it actually help me solve my problem as I fail to see how. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Please provide a working sample for your application. so that I can integrate my solution to fix that